# FlexLayout on a page with TabBar does not wrap its children controls correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am trying to implement a page that displays a scrollable list of buttons, organized on the page in rows of 2. For that I use the following XAML markup:

```xml
<ScrollView>
    <FlexLayout x:Name="flexLayout" Direction="Row" Wrap="Wrap" JustifyContent="SpaceAround" >
    </FlexLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now it works fine when my page is a simple ContentPage:

[image]

But when my page has a TabBar, the wrapping behavior does not work anymore:

[image]

The only difference between the two pages is how they are set in my AppShell.xaml (TestPage is not part of TabBar -> OK TestPage is part of TabBar -> KO):

```xml
<TabBar Route="HomePage">
    <Tab Title="Home">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Tab2">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:TestPage}"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
<ShellContent Title="Test" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:TestPage}" Route="TestPage" />
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is that a known issue with FlexLayout combined with TabBar? Is there a workaround this in that case? Any insight is appreciated, thank you!

The FlexLayout is populated like so (note that I have tried with different controls than Button like Image, and got the same behavior):

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button
        {
            Text = "Button " + i,
            WidthRequest = 100,
            HeightRequest = 100,
        };

        flexLayout.Add(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you render the buttons within `FlexLayout`? According to [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please help add it to the post.

Comment: Have you searched for this in the [issues](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) in the MAUI GitHub repository? This *might* be a bug.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT My bad I thought I did, I have just edited the post.

Comment: @Julian I did search for the issue here, but did not find anything. I will report the bug if nobody spots something wrong in my code.

Comment: @Toto https://stackoverflow.com/a/75245993/6643940 Try restricting it, and specifying horizontal options. Remove the ScrollView for the test.

Comment: Is this ScrollView in a Grid, can I see the whole XAML?

Comment: I tried restricting it horizontally like so: WidthRequest="250", and it does honor it. But it still won't respond to window resizing (I tried all the options in the answer you linked, and removing the ScrollView too). ScrollView is the first and only child of my ContentPage so the whole XAML is here already except for <ContentPage ... /> It is alright for my use case though as it is intended for a mobile app so I will work with WidthRequest as you indicated or a Grid, thanks for your reply

Comment: @Toto Thanks for the update, I can reproduce the issue on Windows. The issue seems to be related with the upper tabbar occupies the horizontal space so the `FlexLayout` fails to resize the window when there's 3 columns of Buttons,  the wrapping behavior does not work anymore. Consider raising an open issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues on Github.